# Display middle of image in header

Tags: html, css

I have image (width = 1920px) and I need to show the whole image at Full HD resolution (width=1920px) the middle of the image at smaller resolutions (see screenshot):
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwqVo.jpg)

Could you help me add CSS style to display center of image at smaller resoultions?

```
    //html:
    <body>
        <div class="header">
        </div>
    </body>

    //css:
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .header{
        background-image: url(Header.png);
        width: 100%;
        height: 292px;    
    }
```

Comment: Could you add the HTML and CSS you already have?

Comment: I've added HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `background-position: center;` to center the image, so when the width is less then the image size, the center will be remain visible.

```css
.header {
  height: 1080px;
  background: url(http://www.cats.club/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/image_header_option.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<header class="header"></header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
background-image: url('path/to/img.png');
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

And optional:

```
background-position: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `background-position: center;` and `background-size: cover;`.
You can find documentation on these attributes and property values **[here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp)**.

See the snippet. The original [image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f4/Flag_of_Christopher_Condent.svg/1000px-Flag_of_Christopher_Condent.svg.png) is of three pirate skulls. Here you can see it is centered on the parent div.

```css
.header {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f4/Flag_of_Christopher_Condent.svg/1000px-Flag_of_Christopher_Condent.svg.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
</div>
```